# GWT plugin for Eclipse Helios installation problem

Tags: gwt, plugins, eclipse-3.6

I just downloaded Eclipse Helios version 3.7.0.

The very first thing I do after starting Eclipse is install the following GWT plugins for Eclipse:

in Install, I set the Work With text field with: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.6

I select the 3 plugins:
- Google App Engine JavaSDK 1.5.0
- Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.6
- Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.3.0

Then I get the following:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.3.0 2.3.0.r36v201105191508 (com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.e36.feature.feature.group 2.3.0.r36v201105191508)
  Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.6 2.3.1.r36v201105191508 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e36.feature.feature.group 2.3.1.r36v201105191508) requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.0,3.7.0)' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.6 2.4.0.ms1_r36v201105101332 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e36.feature.feature.group 2.4.0.ms1_r36v201105101332) requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.0,3.7.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.3.0 2.3.0.r36v201105191508 (com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.e36.feature.feature.group 2.3.0.r36v201105191508)
    To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e36.feature.feature.group 2.3.1

Any idea ???

Comment: It seems I downloaded Eclipse Indigo by mistake, not Helios... this is probably why I got problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's telling you that the plugin doesn't work with Eclipse 3.7 (see the where it says it requires org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.0,3.7.0) ... that's a bracket on the left, and a paren on the right so it's saying 3.6.0 up to, but not including, 3.7.0); like you implied, you'll need to go back to Helios for just a little while longer (I've read 3.7 support is 'imminent')

Answer (score 0):

Change the rights of your eclipse folder so that your user have rights to modify and add files to it, with the user that you wish run it with.

For example:
sudo chown username /opt/eclipse